# How is Flask application actually run when deployed?

Tags: python, flask

I would like some information about how the code gets executed when a Flask application is deployed (say, with gunicorn).

For example, suppose I have the following in `views.py`:

```
foo = [2, 9, 3, 23, 45, 9]
foo.sort()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('base.html', foo=foo)
```

When does `foo` get sorted? Only once when the server starts? Every time there's a request? Something else?

The presence of `before_first_request` and `before_request` in the [documentation](http://before_first_request) seem to offer clues, but I can't understand the problems they're meant to solve until I understand how exactly the code is run on a server.

Can you explain step-by-step (e.g. First A happens, and then B, then C) or point to an on-line resource, please?

Comment: What container are you using for the application?

Comment: Only when the server starts, not for every request. (You could find that out with a `print`.)

Comment: @Ryan: not if the server uses multiprocessing and forks early.

Comment: Why would you have module scope code in a views file for a Flask app like this anyway? What would you expect it to do?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Well, there are some variables that multiple views may want to access. I don't know if this is the right way to do it --- and indeed am considering using database instead --- but it works. This question is part of my effort to figure out the best design for my app.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm using gunicorn on Heroku. (That's what you were asking, right?)

Comment: Look up MVC. This is normally done with a database and state like that lives on the models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question you are asking -- about what happens when -- relates to events that occur upstream of Flask...like when gunicorn starts up.

Flask is a [Web Server Gateway Interface (WSGI) application framework](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/). WSGI is a Python-specific framework that defines how a web server will interface with an application. (The Java equivalent is a [Java servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet).)
The server will use Python's WSGI protocol to call Flask when appropriate. The Flask documentation on [deploying a standalone WSGI application](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/deploying/wsgi-standalone/) shows how to set this up manually, and gives you a little insight into what's going on upstream of Flask.
The section on Gevent is useful because it explicitly shows the import statement for `yourapplication` and its relationship to the HTTP server:

```
from gevent.wsgi import WSGIServer
from yourapplication import app  # if yourapplication imports from views,
                                 # the sort would happen once; here.

http_server = WSGIServer(('', 5000), app)
http_server.serve_forever()
```

The [source code for gunicorn](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py) shows a similar approach, loading the WSGI application once per worker, and then running indefinitely.

### ... Flask's application context

But you may be searching for a way to create some new variable or instantiate a new database connection or establish a unique session cookie -- things that should occur every time a request is processed, and not just once when the application code is loaded.  For this, you should look into Flask's [application context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/appcontext/). From the cited page:

> The application context is created and destroyed as necessary. It never moves
>   between threads and it will not be shared between requests. As such it is the
>   perfect place to store database connection information and other things.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for, and I'm glad it came in before the question was put on hold. I would protest the hold, except it don't think it would make anything better. Anyway, I'm much obliged.